# What is the VOIP Services Certificate used for?

Tags: ios, voip

In Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles on the iOS Developer Portal there is a new option when creating a certificate to make a VOIP Services Certificate:

[image: iOS VOIP Services Certificate]

I work on VOIP apps for iOS and have never seen this option before.  Does anyone know when this certificate would be necessary and what it would be used for?

Comment: Interesting.  If you create one you get the description "Each app you want to use VoIP Services requires its own individual VoIP Services certificate. The App ID-specific VoIP Services certificate allows your notification server to connect to the VoIP Service. Note that only explict App IDs with a specific Bundle Identifier can be used to create a VoIP Service Certificate."  It looks like a new service for VoIP apps to receive notifications?

Comment: Thread here sheds some light - https://devforums.apple.com/message/989162#989162 It is a new push notification type designed for VoIP apps.

Comment: Thanks. That answers my question. Now to learn about PushKit. I hadn't heard of it until now.

Comment: Don't see any real comment on it. I've tried to use it to push, but there are no any pushes in my app. I used it in the same way for ordinary push certificates

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Apple Doc: 
[here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:)

> In iOS 8 and later, voice-over-IP (VoIP) apps register for UIRemoteNotificationTypeVoIP push notifications instead of using this method. Using push notifications eliminates the need for a timeout handler to check in with the VoIP service. Instead, when a calls arrives for the user, the VoIP service sends a VoIP push notification to the user’s device. Upon receiving this notification, the device launches or wakes the app as needed so that it can handle the incoming call.